# gevent library: "Import Error: no module named greenlet"

Tags: python, gevent

hello guys I have downloaded a script that require gevent python library and every time I run the script it says :

```
 File "shodan.py", line 7, in <module>
   from gevent import monkey
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gevent\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
   from gevent.greenlet import Greenlet, joinall, killall
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gevent\greenlet.py", line 6, in <module>
   from gevent.hub import greenlet, getcurrent, get_hub, GreenletExit, Waiter
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gevent\hub.py", line 30, in <module>
   greenlet = __import__('greenlet').greenlet    
ImportError: No module named greenlet
```

I have successfully downloaded and installed gevent and i'm just confused can someone give me the solution and explain the problem.

Comment: `greenlet` is a `gevent` dependency: https://crate.io/packages/greenlet/

Answer (score 16):

Try to install `greenlet` via [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) like so: `pip install greenlet`.

Comment: dude ur my savior!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it to make it work:

1. Download the latest gevent source from github: [gevent](https://github.com/surfly/gevent)
2. replace the source code in C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gevent\ with the download source code.

Answer (score 0):

while running the command

> python app.py

instead try

> python2.7 app.py

worked for me ....

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you have *gevent* installed**:

Check that you don't have another file in the same folder named as *gevent.py*, because if yes then when you do "*import gevent*" it's importing/calling that file that you named *gevent.py*.

Change the filename and it should work.