# Import Error: No module named greenlet

Tags: python-2.7, openerp-7

I have installed gevent but when I try to start my server with gevent it shows an import error as shown below:

```
C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server\openerp-server --gevent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openerp-server", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server\.\openerp\cli
\__init__.py", line 60, in main
    o.run(args)
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server\.\openerp\cli
\server.py", line 281, in run
    main(args)
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server\.\openerp\cli
\server.py", line 226, in main
    import gevent
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server\.\gevent\__in
it__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from gevent.hub import get_hub, iwait, wait
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server\.\gevent\hub.
py", line 8, in <module>
    import greenlet  # http://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet/
ImportError: No module named greenlet
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [gevent library: "Import Error: no module named greenlet"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322247/gevent-library-import-error-no-module-named-greenlet)

Comment: Your error shows that Python could not find a module named greenlet. Have you tried to understand why this happened? EDIT: please look at the link in the other comment.

Comment: I've already added greelet module but I couldn't able to understand why its thoroughgoing error I am new to python